# Error in logstash configuration file tomcat

Tags: configuration, logstash

I have problem with Logstash configuration
My logs pattern are

```
2017-07-26 14:31:03,644 INFO  [http-bio-10.60.2.21-10267-exec-92] jsch.DeployManagerFileUSImpl (DeployManagerFileUSImpl.java:132) - passage par ficher temporaire .bindings.20170726-143103.tmp
```

My current pattern is

```
match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level} \(%{DATA:class}\):%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
```

Which pattern for `[http-bio-10.60.2.21-10267-exec-92]` and for `jsch.DeployManagerFileUSImpl`?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like the current pattern you've shown would work, as you don't have anything in your sample message that matches `\(%{DATA:class}\):%{GREEDYDATA:message}` and you're not dealing with the double space after the loglevel.

If you want to match some random stuff in the middle of a line, use %{DATA}, e.g.:

> \[%{DATA:myfield}\]

and then you can use %{GREEDYDATA} to get the stuff at the end of the line:

> \[%{DATA:myfield1}\] %{GREEDYDATA:myfield2}

If you need to break these items down into fields of their own, then be more specific with the pattern or use a second grok{} block.

Answer (score 0):

in my logstash.conf i have change my pattern to

```
match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate},%{INT} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level}  \[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\] %{JAVACLASS:package} \(%{JAVAFILE:file}:%{INT:line}\) - %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
```

With helping of site https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ .

But i could not see in kibana 5.4.3 my static log file contains in /home/elasticsearch/static_logs/ directory ?

### My logstash configuration file with "static" section

```
input { 
    file {
        type => "access-log"
         path => "/home/elasticsearch/tomcat/logs/*.txt"
    }
    file {
        type => "tomcat"
        path => "/home/elasticsearch/tomcat/logs/*.log" exclude => "*.zip"
        codec => multiline {
          negate => true
          pattern => "(^%{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, 20%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}) (?:AM|PM))"
          what => "previous"
        }
    }
        file {
        type => "static"
        path => "/home/elasticsearch/static_logs/*.log" exclude => "*.zip"
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "access-log" {
        grok {
            # Access log pattern is %a %{waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter.PRINCIPAL}s %t %m %U%q %s %B %T &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;
            match => [ "message" , "%{IPV4:clientIP} %{NOTSPACE:user} \[%{DATA:timestamp}\] %{WORD:method} %{NOTSPACE:request} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:bytesSent} %{NUMBER:duration} \"%{NOTSPACE:referer}\" \"%{DATA:userAgent}\"" ]
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
        }
        grok{
            match => [ "request", "/%{USERNAME:app}/" ]
            tag_on_failure => [ ]
        }
        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
            remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
        }
        geoip {
            source => ["clientIP"]
        }
        dns {
            reverse => [ "clientIP" ]
        }
        mutate {
            lowercase => [ "user" ]
            convert => [ "bytesSent", "integer", "duration", "float" ]
        }
        if [referer] == "-" {
            mutate {
                remove_field => [ "referer" ]
            }
        }
        if [user] == "-" {
            mutate {
                remove_field => [ "user" ]
            }
        }
    }
    if [type] == "tomcat" {
        if [message] !~ /(.+)/  {
            drop { }
        }
        grok{
             patterns_dir => "./patterns"
             overwrite => [ "message" ]
            # oK Catalina normal
             match => [ "message", "%{CATALINA_DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:className} %{WORD:methodName}\r\n%{LOGLEVEL: logLevel}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
        }
        grok{
            match => [ "path", "/%{USERNAME:app}.20%{NOTSPACE}.log"]
            tag_on_failure => [ ]
        }
        # Aug 25, 2014 11:23:31 AM
        date{
            match => [ "timestamp", "MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss a" ]
            remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
        }
    }
        if [type] == "static" {
        if [message] !~ /(.+)/  {
            drop { }
        }
        grok{
             patterns_dir => "./patterns"
             overwrite => [ "message" ]
            # 2017-08-03 16:01:11,352 WARN  [Thread-552] pcf2.AbstractObjetMQDAO (AbstractObjetMQDAO.java:137) - Descripteur de
            match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate},%{INT} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level}  \[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\] %{JAVACLASS:package} \(%{JAVAFILE:file}:%{INT:line}\) - %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
        }
        # 2017-08-03 16:01:11,352
        date{
            match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,SSS" ]
            remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
        }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["192.168.99.100:9200"]}

}
```

---

Where is my mistake ?
Regards